# Bootstrap4 Dropdown menu fill input-group

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, dropdown, popper.js

I have a very simple bootstrap issue that I'd like to solve.

According to the guide (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) the `.dropdown-menu` class and dropdown-toggle has to be wrapped within `.dropdown`, or another element that declares `position: relative;`.

But so far, I can only get it to work if I place the `.dropdown-menu` at the same level as my toggle. Because of this, I'm only able to get a small dropdown on the right hand corner like this.

[image: Not Desired Result]

However, if I were to move the entire `.dropdown-menu` div block down by two levels (inside the `.input-group .dropdown` div block), I'd achieve an effect like this ...

[image: Desired, but script broken]

... which is exactly what I wanted, however, on the console, bootstrap/popper would then spew out an error telling me that `Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined`, and the dropdown menu would not retract anymore, and that's where I'm stuck.

I have included a working code sample (first image) in the bottom for you to try, and please tell me if I'm using the dropdown class wrong?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="input-group dropdown">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project_search" placeholder="search ...">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn bg-primary text-white" type="button">Search</button>
            <button class="btn bg-primary text-white dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="searchAdvancedFilter" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="caret"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right w-100" aria-labelledby="searchAdvancedFilter">
              <h6 class="dropdown-header">Advanced Settings</h6>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have figured out a way to resolve my issue, but then I encountered yet with another question, first of all, here's the code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="input-group dropdown">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project_search" placeholder="search ...">
        <button class="btn bg-primary text-white" type="button">Search</button>
        <button class="btn bg-primary text-white dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="searchAdvancedFilter" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="caret"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right w-100" aria-labelledby="searchAdvancedFilter">
          <h6 class="dropdown-header">Advanced Settings</h6>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I've done is I've removed both `.input-group-append` div and `.btn-group` div, and have my `.dropdown-menu` right under `.dropdown`, as well as having the toggle at the same level with the menu. Everything works fine ... expect the `.input-group` / `.btn-group` styles are now ruined.

Without manually using CSS class to override them, is there anything wrong with my class structure with the previous version that has caused it not to function what I wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the containing `btn-group` `position:static` like this...

https://www.codeply.com/go/6kJ3E53PuF

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="input-group dropdown">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project_search" placeholder="search ...">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="btn-group position-static">
            <button class="btn bg-primary text-white" type="button">Search</button>
            <button class="btn bg-primary text-white dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="searchAdvancedFilter" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="caret"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right w-100" aria-labelledby="searchAdvancedFilter">
              <h6 class="dropdown-header">Advanced Settings</h6>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**How it works:**

The `dropdown-menu` in Bootstrap 4 is `position:absolute`, and by default, the `btn-group` is `position:relative`. A `position:absolute` element inside a `position:relative` container will size relative to the container. However, when a `position:absolute` element is placed inside a `position:static` container, **it will no longer resize relative to the container**. This is allowing the `dropdown-menu` to size the full-width of the `dropdown`. [See this example of absolute inside relative vs. static](https://www.codeply.com/go/ZAVmUrU5AS).

Comment: mind explain why does the `.position-static` is used, and how does this class work in the spot where you placed it?